# I am using jquery $.post for Updating form data to MVC method,but sometimes the ajax post call gets aborted

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

```
if (_form.valid() && isValid == true) {

        $.post(getUrlFromRootPath(_form.attr("action")), _form.serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data.isvalid != null && data.isvalid == false) {
                }
         });
```

On browser network traffic it shows request aborted.

Comment: Please include all needed code in your question that could help us identify your issue. But it seems that you are missing [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on submit.

Comment: I am using input type as button and not submit button , so do we need to include event.preventdefault() for simple button.

Comment: In that case your issue is somewhere else. But **please** include all needed code in your question that could help us identify your issue.